# How to Discuss on Meta

Tags: discussion

Many of the Meta questions or discussions have comments only. I do not have enough reputation to comment. Does this fact mean that I cannot participate in the many discussion on Meta? Or am I allowed to post answers to discussions in an answer form when it would really be a comment instead?

Comment: Basically, if you have something to add to the discussion (that is more than 1 sentence long) add it as an answer. That way it can be voted on, and people can show their support or disagreement for what you say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment everywhere privilege enabling you to leave comments on other people's posts is awarded at a reputation of 50. Which you can reach quite fast answering or asking a few questions.

While you're gaining those reputation points feel free to use answers on meta* to discuss issues of your interest. The mods can also convert answers to comments if need be - again just try to not over do it. Be sure to indicate which answer you're refering to.

---

<sup>* unless you start discussions on 200 topics or so.</sup>

Comment: So this means that even though it would be more suitable for a comment I can still put the stuff I want to say in a answer form?

Comment: As long as it is meta and not the main site... and given only a manageable amount of answers... yes, I think that we can handle that. Just don't overuse it.

Answer (score -4):

I think the comment only after 50 reputation is bad. It forces beginners into pushing question answers where there in fact are no answers. Why not treating answers and comments evenly?

Comment: see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174